# trigger animation whenever the <img src={value} /> src value changes

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I'm using React to Create an `img` element that changes its `src` attribute after specific time with `setInterval` function based on an array that contains many images.

so the thing is i want to make an animation whenever the `src` attribute changes, i was thinking of using `React.useEffect()` hook to watch the `src` changes and add some animation but i couldn't go further logically.

my code :

```js
import Canada from "../images/Canada.jpg"
import Tokyo from "../images/Tokyo.jpg"
import NewYork from "../images/NewYork.jpg"
import southKorea from "../images/southKorea.jpg"


function AboutMe() {

    const imgArray = [NewYork, Tokyo, Canada, southKorea]
     let i = 0;
    const maxImgArray = imgArray.length -1 ;
    const swap = function() {
        let image = imgArray[i];
        i = (i === maxImgArray) ? 0 : ++i;
        const attr = document.getElementById("moving-image");
        attr.src=image;
    }
    setInterval(swap, 5000)
    return (
    <section className="About-me">
        <h1>About me</h1>
        <div className="container">
        <div className="cities-images">
            <img 
            src={Tokyo}
            alt="NewYork" id="moving-image"></img>
            <label class="switch">
              <input type="checkbox"/>
              <span class="slider round"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
            <div className="info">
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>    
    )
}
```

Comment: You know when the src is being changed so why not set the animation then (by adding a class)? You will have to sense when it has finished also (animationend) so you can remove that class ready for the next time.

Comment: you can put the <img src={stateValue}/> in a state and when change the src stateValue, can trigger the animation inside useEffect.

Comment: @AHaworth you mean by using ```attr.classList.add()``` and then ```attr.classList.remove()```?

Comment: use from `useState` and `useEffect` together

Comment: @DevThiman can you make a pen about it? i've tried it but whenever the ```src``` changes it goes back for the first image which is the default value and then moves for the next image, also i need to know how to add animation in js

Comment: @AbArabi create a pen or sandbox what you have done up to now and share it. I'll check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `useState` hook in react, we can re-render the component with updated value. So for `src` change, we can use useState to update the current src of the image.

By using `useEffect` hook we can do anything once `src` state change like set different animations.

**Component State**

```
  const [image, setImage] = useState(Usa);
  const [imageIndex, setImageIndex] = useState(0);
  const imgArray = [Usa, Japan, Canada, SouthKorea];
```

**useEffect**

```
useEffect(() => {
let interval = null;
if (i !== maxImgArray) {
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    let image = imgArray[imageIndex];
    const attr = document.getElementById("moving-image");
    attr.src = image;
    // update the img index to state
    setImageIndex((imageIndex) =>
      imageIndex === maxImgArray ? 0 : imageIndex + 1
    );
    // update the src in state.
    setImage(attr.src);
  }, 3000);
}
// When our code runs and reruns for every render, useEffect also cleans up after itself using the cleanup function.
// Here we clear the interval to remove the effects that could happen with state change while interval.
return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [image, imageIndex]); // when image, imageIndex gets change, useEffect will be triggered.
```

**Component** here I used framer-motion for animation.

```
<section className="Country-flag">
    <h1>Country Flag</h1>
    <div className="container">
      <motion.div
        key={image}
        animate={{ x: 100, opacity: 1 }}
        transition={{
          delay: 1,
          x: { type: "spring", stiffness: 100 },
          default: { duration: 2 }
        }}
      >
        {/* when state {image} value change, this component will re-render with new src */}
        <img alt="NewYork" src={image} id="moving-image"></img>
      </motion.div>
      <div className="info"></div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Check this sample [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/animate-img-src-value-change-71985572-u06sqq?file=/src/App.js:1428-2041) for produced code.

If you want different animations for each img, then add another state variable for animation and change the value inside the useEffect for each image state.